# Is it possible to use ESLint to lint Handlebars template?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, eslint

I'm trying to write an ESLint plugin for Ember to check if the handlebars template together with javascript code has no issues.

To achieve that, I need to lint `.js` component code together with `.hbs` component template.

I don't have much experience with writing ESLint rules, but I guess all I need is to somehow turn those `.hbs` files into AST and then lint it as usually, but I don't know how to do that.

Are those AST produced by Js and Handlebars even compatible?

Comment: I am not sure, you could try it out. https://astexplorer.net/. It looks like the AST does handle handlebars so I am sure there is an option for it

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible, but maybe [ember-template-lint](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-template-lint) can help you.

Comment: @Pete I would like to check wether the template variables are present in the component js file

Comment: Not sure if this is what you need https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-hbs

Comment: did you find a way?

Comment: You can go to http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/ and copy paste your hbs content there and click on "Compile handlebar template". This is one cool shortcut to see any lint error for hbs.

Answer (score 1):

I believe https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-html does what you're looking for:

> A[n] ESLint plugin to lint and fix inline scripts contained in HTML
> files.

By default, this plugin will only consider files ending with those extensions as HTML: .erb, .handlebars, .hbs, .htm, .html, .mustache, .nunjucks, .php, .tag, .twig, .we. You can set your own list of HTML extensions by using this setting.